# How do I change the background of this button from blue to orange?

Tags: html, css

I'm using this CSS file:

https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/css/add-ons1.css

Here's the code for the form I'm using:

```
  <form id="myform">
    <div class="block form-group">
      <input type='text' required="required"/ style="width:300px;">
    </div>

    <div class="block">
      <button type="submit" class="button">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

I've tried to figure out how to change the button color from blue to orange, but I'm getting incredibly confused with all of the CSS lines. I tried to force some css styling into the button, but I think I'm messing up somewhere since all of my changes makes the button just look weird but doesn't actually change the color.

I inspected element and tried to make changes to various lines and I tried copying the CSS to my own website thinking it might be a caching issue, but whatever I try, I can't get the button to change from blue to orange, lol.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. In the latter: "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so— **but also copy the code into the question itself**. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time. Use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to make a live demo of inline JavaScript/HTML/CSS."

Comment: when you want to change the color of button??

Comment: don't know whether you can edit the css you have posted, if you can- check the possible answer mentioned below..

Comment: Use you browser dev tools inspect facility to see exactly who/where is setting what CSS for that button. It may be that some library or system you are using is setting !important for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why you should be getting *'confused with lines of css'*

why not add a class

```
.orange{
  background: orange;
}
```

to the end of your css file,

and add `orange` to your `html` button code

```
 <form id="myform">
  <div class="block form-group">
    <input type='text' required="required"/ style="width:300px;">
  </div>

 <div class="block">
   <button type="submit" class="button orange">Submit</button>
 </div>
</form>
```

let me know

Comment: Hah! That worked. Wow, I tried to do something like that but it never worked.  It looks like you used two classes? button and orange? I don't know CSS very well, so it's kinda like a tweaking thing for me. Do you know how I can change the hover background color? It's currently orange and then hovers gray.

Comment: @runguy2911 if it worked, can you mark it as answer, you can click the tick mark near the left of the answer .  
for more queries write another question..